# Adding Subtitles to a Youtube link I'm sending to a deaf person

Tags: youtube

I have a friend I send Youtube likes to, she is deaf.
I would like to send those links with closed caption or subtitles forced to open when the video starts.
How do I edit the links to include this?
Here is an example of a link I would like to do this to. It has closed caption
How to I for CC to open?

This is the URL from the address bar:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yj0fZ5waq5g
This is the link from the Share button under the video:
https://youtu.be/Yj0fZ5waq5g

Thanks so vary much, PA

Answer (score 1):

It's a couple of settings she would need to enable from her account settings page called "Always show captions" and "Include auto-generated captions (when available)"

https://www.youtube.com/account_playback